# How to use two data frames to run a linear regression with a for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop, linear-regression

I am trying to conduct a simple linear regression analysis using a data frame with 4 columns (all of which are dependent variables) and a dataframe having 194 rows and 212 columns. 
I have 5 other data frames to use as dependent variable for the same analysis

I have achieved the desired results but I need to scale this out, I have tried to add in an extra for loop (for the columns of the dependent variable) but i would also need to simultaneously create more empty lists.

I would like to know how would I achieve this?

My current for-loop is:

```
y <- data.frame(Green_Class_Commercial[,-1])
x <- data.frame(lagvar[1:175,c(-1,-2)])
out <- data.frame(NULL)              # create object to keep results

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  m <- summary(lm(y[,1] ~ x[,i]))    # run model
  out[i, 1] <- names(x)[i]           # print variable name
  out[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  out[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
  out[i, 4] <-m$coefficients[2,4]    # Pvalue
  out[i,5] <-m$r.squared             # R-squared
}
names(out) <- c("Variable", "Intercept", "Coefficient","P-val","R-square")
head(out)
```

Giving the output

```
> head(out)
               Variable Intercept   Coefficient     P-val     R-square
1                GDP.SC 0.2540527 -4.722220e-07 0.7032087 8.411229e-04
2               GDP.SC1 0.1148311  3.107631e-07 0.7959237 3.899366e-04
3               GDP.SC2 0.1609010  4.998762e-08 0.9673014 9.855831e-06
4               GDP.SC3 0.1353608  1.959274e-07 0.8746321 1.468544e-04
5               GDP.SC4 0.1439931  1.487237e-07 0.9064221 8.200597e-05
6 CivilianLaborForce.SC 0.2595231 -4.078450e-08 0.7716514 4.881398e-04
>
```

So Here is the Variables I want to run the regression

```
#The x Variable
structure(list(GDP.SC = c(154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 
160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4
), GDP.SC1 = c(NA, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 
160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4), 
    GDP.SC2 = c(NA, NA, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
    154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 160138.4, 160138.4, 
    160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4
    ), GDP.SC3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
    154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 160138.4, 
    160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4
    ), GDP.SC4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 
    154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 154698, 160138.4, 
    160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4, 160138.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

#The Y Variable
structure(list(X = 1:20, ComBus = c(0.83, 0, 0.23, 0.09, 0.1, 
0.11, 0.15, 0.18, 0.37, 0.19, 0, 0.18, 0.09, 0.1, 0.03, 0.5, 
0.14, 0.17, 0.11, 0.06), ComCon = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 
NA, 0.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0), ComNoo = c(0.25, 
0.14, 0.38, 0.17, 0.14, 0.33, 0.44, 0.05, 0.04, 0.1, 0.18, 0.06, 
0.23, 0.14, 0.5, 0.14, 0.5, 0, 0.14, 0.23), ComOO = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.33, 0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.22, 0.15, 0, 0, 0.17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: applying it onto other data frames? this sentence "I need to scale this out, I have tried to add in an extra for loop" is a bit vague and your example doesn't show what else you will like to do

Comment: Why not keep all regression data in a single data frame?

Comment: Hey, there are several possible solutions to this one. If you require doing the same thing lots of times I would usually write it as a function and feed it the dataframes (or `map` it to the dataframes). Something like this that outputs each `lm` as a list element: `lm_func <- function(d1, df2) {
  out <- apply(df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) {
    lm(df2[, 1] ~ x)
  })
  return(out)
}`

`broom::glance` might be useful here too. I can try give a more full answer if this is on the right lines for you.

Comment: @StupidWolf Sorry about that, so ```y=Green_Class_Commercial``` is a dataframe with 175 rows and 4 columns , I also have 5 similar data frames for that i need to substitute in for y (All of which have four columns) that i need to be the response variable in the regression model.  X is a dataframe with 194 rows and 212 columns (And i need to run a simple linear regression one at a time with each of the 212 variables). In my current code i have done that for one column of the  Green_Class_Commercial dataframe and i wish to do this again with columns 2-4. Let me know if this helps thanks

Comment: @Parfait thanks for the reply, That would make sorting through the dataset much harder. The Y variables represent the probability that someone defaults on a loan in greenville south carolina, this was a dataset given to me by my professor for my current class many of those probabilities were filtered based on status (classified or passed ) and location (Greenville or other ) also 6 other diffferent sectors (Consumer business, commercial business etc. )

Comment: @QAsena thanks for the help, yes would you mind explaining that a bit more? when you say ```apply(df, ``` which data frame would this refer too? would i use this in the for loop? thank you again

Comment: @Jerald Achaibar. `apply` is replacing the loop in this case. I find it easier to work with in many cases. I've posted an answer which is more carefully explained using `x_df` and `y_df`.  Possibly using `glance` is not the right option, let me know.

Comment: In `lm` you can refer to named columns of data frame, using *data* argument. Please `dput` your data or mock up sample data for [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I will show how easy it is to use a single data frame with dynamic formula for `lm`.

Comment: @Parfait @QAsena Thank you all so much for the help, I have figured out how to do the `dput` function and have included that in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a nested `lapply` with outer call traversing each column of dependent variable data frame and each time inner call iterates through all columns of independent variable data frame:

```
reg_data <- function(yvar, xdf) {
    # ITERATE THROUGH EACH COLUMN OF x
    df_list <- lapply(seq_along(xdf), function(i) {
      m <- summary(lm(yvar ~ x[,i]))        # run model

      data.frame(
         Variable = names(x)[i],            # print variable name
         Intercept = m$coefficients[1,1],   # intercept
         Coefficient = m$coefficients[2,1], # coefficient
         P_val = m$coefficients[2,4],       # P-value
         R_square = m$r.squared             # R-squared
      )
    })

   return(do.call(rbind, df_list))
}

# ITERATE THROUGH EACH COLUMN OF y
model_dfs <- lapply(y[-1], function(col) reg_data(col, x))
```

**Output**

```
model_dfs

# $ComBus
#   Variable  Intercept   Coefficient     P_val    R_square
# 1   GDP.SC  2.6988486 -1.599147e-05 0.3262406 0.053555129
# 2  GDP.SC1 -0.1802638  2.083180e-06 0.8452577 0.002304901
# 3  GDP.SC2  0.4443504 -1.838100e-06 0.8656578 0.001843828
# 4  GDP.SC3 -0.2114691  2.310754e-06 0.8410848 0.002767098
# 5  GDP.SC4 -0.4596142  3.921280e-06 0.7517165 0.007381776

# $ComCon
#   Variable  Intercept  Coefficient     P_val    R_square
# 1   GDP.SC -0.4342988 3.752788e-06 0.8970060 0.001154220
# 2  GDP.SC1 -1.5050149 1.056908e-05 0.7148913 0.009154924
# 3  GDP.SC2 -2.2666678 1.549256e-05 0.6144502 0.018606737
# 4  GDP.SC3 -3.2822050 2.205720e-05 0.5032585 0.035178198
# 5  GDP.SC4 -4.7039571 3.124770e-05 0.3808557 0.064522691

# $ComNoo
#   Variable   Intercept  Coefficient     P_val    R_square
# 1   GDP.SC -0.02348033 1.470480e-06 0.9087818 0.000749555
# 2  GDP.SC1 -0.33062799 3.410697e-06 0.8011075 0.003836926
# 3  GDP.SC2 -1.11901191 8.455261e-06 0.5536610 0.022365205
# 4  GDP.SC3 -1.58084828 1.134370e-05 0.4400999 0.040243587
# 5  GDP.SC4 -2.12276002 1.482734e-05 0.3493362 0.062765524

# $ComOO
#   Variable   Intercept   Coefficient     P_val    R_square
# 1   GDP.SC -0.03430512  5.514300e-07 0.9481025 0.000241968
# 2  GDP.SC1  1.13773433 -6.882664e-06 0.4347716 0.036277535
# 3  GDP.SC2  1.98603902 -1.226932e-05 0.1785540 0.110105644
# 4  GDP.SC3  1.89971836 -1.171132e-05 0.2291494 0.094842038
# 5  GDP.SC4  1.78462415 -1.096733e-05 0.2963624 0.077531366
```

## <kbd>[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/EPASI73875)</kbd>

Comment: !!!! This is exactly what i needed thank you so much for the help. @Parfait ! Now i noticed you have a negative in front of the the coefficient for the p-value is there a particular reason for this? Also I am having some issues a wide range of p-values, and error when i try do this same regression without the lapply saying the number of rows differ. Could this cause the discrepancy in the P-values i am getting?

Comment: @Parfait Interesting use of `lapply` there. Not used it with `seq_along` before. Up-vote for that.

Comment: Negative p-values was a typing error. I removed hyphen before its extracted value from *coefficients* table. Vectors in `lm` must be the same length to run properly so no you cannot run regression across different length data frames.

Comment: hello again @Parfait, needing some additional assistance here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235586/how-to-run-run-multiple-regression-and-prediction-for-multiple-columns-of-data)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, is this good for you? I'm replacing the loop with apply if that is ok?

```
### Some dummy dataframes
x <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(1:10),
                 v2 = rnorm(1:10),
                 v3 = runif(10, 1, 1000),
                 v4 = runif(10, 1, 1000))
x2 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(1:10),
                v2 = rnorm(1:10),
                v3 = runif(10, 1, 1000),
                v4 = runif(10, 1, 1000))
y <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(1:10),
                v2 = rnorm(1:10),
                v3 = runif(10, 1, 1000),
                v4 = runif(10, 1, 1000))
y2 <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(1:10),
                 v2 = rnorm(1:10),
                 v3 = runif(10, 1, 1000),
                 v4 = runif(10, 1, 1000)) 

###
# I tend to prefer the apply family of functions to replace loops where possible.
# This function takes two inputs, dataframes of dependent and independent variables.
# the apply function here takes the x_df and applies the following anonymous function to each column
# so for each column in x_df it performs a lm against the first column of y_df

lm_func <- function(y_df, x_df) {
  out <- apply(x_df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) {
    lm(y_df[, 1] ~ x)
  })
  return(out)
}

results_list <- lm_func(y, x)

# the output is one list element per lm. I like to keep the whole lm output just in case you need to go back to it

# we can then turn that list back into a dataframe using rbindlist from data.table
# and get what I think is your desired output using glance from broom

library(data.table)
library(broom)

results_glance <- rbindlist(lapply(results_list, glance), idcol = "var_name")

# or keep it as a list if you wish
results_list_glance <- lapply(results_list, glance)

# to run the function using a single x argument but multiple y arguments you can use mapply

results_list_m <- mapply(lm_func,
                       y_df = list(y, y2),
                       MoreArgs = list(    # other arguments you want to keep fixed
                         x_df = x
                       ),
                       SIMPLIFY = F
)

# the output is a little fiendish because it will be a list of lists
# we can include the rbindlist and glance into the function to make the output a little simpler:


lm_func_bind <- function(y_df, x_df) {
  out <- apply(x_df, MARGIN = 2, function(x) {
    lm(y_df[, 1] ~ x)
  })
  out <- rbindlist(lapply(out, glance), idcol = "var_name")
  return(out)
}
results_glance_df <- lm_func_bind(y, x)

results_list_dfs <- mapply(lm_func_bind,
                           y_df = list(y, y2),
                           MoreArgs = list(    # other arguments you want to keep fixed
                             x_df = x
                           ),
                           SIMPLIFY = F
)
```

Let me know if I can make this better. If you are not familiar with some of the functions like `apply` and `rbindlist` they are worth checking out the documentation for.
Cheers!

P.S. Usually repeated linear models is not ideal due to chance of success. That is more of a question of stats rather than coding though!

Comment: This was very informational, thank you for taking the time to walk me through step by step! However the only problem is now i get different p-values, any idea why this would be happening? I used  ``` head(results_glance[1:5,c(1,6)])```
and the results were very different compared to above.

Comment: var_name   p.value
1:   GDP.SC 0.9894016
2:  GDP.SC1 0.9957419
3:  GDP.SC2 0.9998764
4:  GDP.SC3 0.9978171
5:  GDP.SC4 0.9951122

Comment: mmm I'm not sure. If I run your loop on the same dummy dataframes as my example I get the same result for both. Tricky to check over without a reproducible example, can you provide one? `dput(YOURDATA)`, or `head(dput(YOURDATA), n = 20)` can help if the frames are not crazy large. Any leftover objects or something in your environment? Maybe test on a fresh R session if you haven't already? Or maybe your real dataframes are a little more complicated than the simple dummy ones?

Comment: I might have spotted the problem, In your comment above you mention substititing 5 dataframes for `y`. The code I gave you the `y` dataframe stays the same and `x`  dataframe changes... Easy to fix if this is my mistake, just let me know and I'll update the answer,

Comment: yes i see this now, the Y data frame is the one I am changing, Thank you

Comment: Ok, I swapped the x and y in the `mapply` call. Now y changes and x stays the same. This work for you?  It's a little tricky for me to read the data from your comments directly into R as they are not formatted. the `dput()` function provides a structure that can easily be copy-pasted in and you can give it just a slice of your data for example: `dput(data[1:10,1:3])`. You can paste the output from `dput()` into your question so that anyone can experiment with it.

Comment: I have added the dput in the question thank you @QAsena! The change you made to the mapply function seems like it would work however i get the following when i try to rbind  i get `results_glance2 <- rbindlist(lapply(results_list_m, glance), idcol = "var_name")Error: No glance method recognized for this list.`

Comment: yep, so `results_list_m` runs the function `lm_func` and gives a list of lists so you would need `rbindlist(lapply(unlist(results_list_m, recursive = F), glance), idcol = "var_name")` . Or you could use the second function `lm_func_bind` which uses `rbindlist` along the way and gives a list of `tibbles`/`dataframes` already bound.. The `mapply` stuff takes a bit of getting used to.

Comment: hello again @QAsena, needing some additional assistance here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235586/how-to-run-run-multiple-regression-and-prediction-for-multiple-columns-of-data)